# cannot get web.config file in area folder to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created a new area "admin", add following code to web.config in the admin area.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/admin/login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

if I go to admin page without logging in, I still get redirected to  ~/account/login page.  seems like the web.config in admin area didnt overwrite the web.config file in the root folder.  not sure whats wrong, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web.config` in area folder can not specify runtime behavior. Its only function is to define some options pertaining to view compilation.

Comment: So this is completely different than in web forms where you could add appSettings and such and access them within subfolders. Adding app settings within area and trying to access from a controller wouldn't work then?